# Stage.setScene() appears to ignore maxHeight/Width settings

Tags: java, javafx, java-11

OS: Linux Mint 18.3, Java **11**.

Here's an SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class SceneSwitcher extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch( args);
    }
    Button btnSwitchToScene2;
    Scene scene1;
    Button btnSwitchToScene1;
    Scene scene2;
    Stage stage;
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        stage = primaryStage;


        stage.setMinHeight( 500 );
        stage.setMaxHeight( 500 );
        // stage.setHeight( 500 );

        stage.setMinWidth( 1000 );
        stage.setMaxWidth( 1000 );
        // stage.setWidth( 1000 );

        stage.setResizable( false );

        btnSwitchToScene2 = new Button();
        btnSwitchToScene2.setText("Switch!");
        btnSwitchToScene2.setOnAction(  e ->
            btnSwitchToScene2_Click()  );
        VBox pane1 = new VBox(10);
        pane1.getChildren().addAll( btnSwitchToScene2);
        scene1 = new Scene(pane1, 250, 150);
        btnSwitchToScene2 = new Button();
        btnSwitchToScene2.setText("Switch!");
        btnSwitchToScene2.setOnAction( e ->
            btnSwitchToScene1_Click() );
        HBox pane2 = new HBox(10);
        pane2.getChildren().addAll( btnSwitchToScene2);
        scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 300, 75);
        // Set the stage with scene 1 and show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Scene Switcher");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    private void btnSwitchToScene2_Click()
    {
        stage.setScene(scene2);
    }
    private void btnSwitchToScene1_Click()
    {
        stage.setScene(scene1);
    }
}
```

The first showing has the right dimensions. As you change the `Scene`s however, although the `resizable == false` remains, the dimensions of the window (`Stage`) adjust to match the `Scene`s.

Is this intended behaviour? If so what should I do to keep a fixed-dimension `Stage`?

Something even more inexplicable happens if you uncomment the line `stage.setHeight( 500 );`: on my machine when you click the Switch button the window stays the same size but goes completely black.

In Swing these sorts of settings were quite tricky, and the rule of thumb was to use `setPreferredHeight/Width/Size`, etc. and allow the framework to take care of things. How does it work in JavaFX?